# I have problem in using radio button "flutter"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, dart-null-safety

I doubt they developed radio button that's why my code is not working I checked flutter.dev but I didn't see something new ,Then I realized that the error is in the dart data types I use `string` where is the problem??

```
   lass _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String feel;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
```

radio button code :

```
            Text('good'),
            Radio(
                value: "good",
                groupValue: feel,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    feel = val;
                    print(feel);
                  });
                })
```

can someone help me find what's wrong??

Comment: what is your issue ?

Comment: @eamirho3ein There is a red line under the word feel ( string feel ) and problem that the all code isn't work because of that

Comment: Whenever you get a red underline because of an error the IDE will exactly tell you what's wrong when you hover your mouse cursor over it

Comment: Did try setting feel as optional or set initial value?

Comment: @Ivo I didn't study computer science, programming is just an hobby for me, so I don't always understand the explanation that comes above the red line anyway thank you for saying to me

Comment: You're welcome. For next time, even if you don't understand the explanation, it might be helpful to write in the question what it says. It might help others solve the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You need define `feel` as `nullable` because the `onChange` function of `Radio` return a `nullable` value , try this:

```
String? feel;
```

and also define `Radio` type like this:

```
Radio<String>(//<--- add this
          value: "good",
          groupValue: feel,
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              feel = val;
              print(feel);
            });
          }),
```

Comment: And "onChanged: (String? val)"

Comment: @Fugipe by default it is `onChanged: (String? val)` when you use `onChanged: (val)`

Comment: Thank you. I tried it the error gone but A new error appeared on the semicolon after `feel = val` ??

Comment: what it say? @lucy

Comment: @lucy define your radio as `Radio<String>(`

Comment: @Ivo is right I forgot to mention that

Comment: oh that I've put `(String? val )` and everything is okay now thank you so much for helping

Comment: When you define the radio type don't need to define the type in onChange function. @lucy

Comment: @lucy true, that's also possible yeah. But personally I would say it's cleaner to put the type where I said it. But that's subjective maybe. Both ways should solve it